# Using JQuery - Auto Complete Text Box In ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to autocomplete textbox with items from a database table; however it is not auto completing. No information is not pulling from the database even though there's data. What am I doing differently that the autocomplete is not working.

```
<head runat="server">

 <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SearchText();  
    });  
    function SearchText() {  
        $("#txtInvoiceNum").autocomplete({  
            source: function(request, response) {  
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url: "LoadSheet.aspx/GetInvoice",  
                    data: "{'invoiceNum':'" + document.getElementById('txtInvoiceNum').value + "'}",  
                    dataType: "json",  
                    success: function(data) {  
                        response(data.d);  
                    },  
                    error: function(result) {  
                        alert("No Match");  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceNum" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

  [WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetInvoice(string invoiceNum)
{
    List<string> empResult = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Top 10 SOPNUMBE from [TWCL].[dbo].[SOP10100] where  SOPNUMBE LIKE ''+@SearchInvoice+'%'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchInvoice", invoiceNum);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                empResult.Add(dr["SOPNUMBE"].ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
            return empResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does AJAX request and response works? do you get the expected data in the response? (they should not be shown, but do they come as json object?)

Comment: In executing i'm not seeing anything happens

Comment: In your `success: function (data) { ... HERE ... },` please add this: `console.log(data);` and share the results, I would prefer to install Fiddler as well to observe the request and response. For now, try what I said and tell me what you get.

Comment: it is not responding

Comment: OK then try to debug your method `GetInvoice`, set a break point at the beginning of it, is it being called?

Comment: I did that but it is not being called. Maybe something is wrong with the url; because the aspx is within a folder

Comment: I am not ASP.Net expert (only ASP.Net *core*) therefore I cannot really help, but your function and the whole code is very much complicated for a code that is not being called. Try to call a very very simple function using AJAX, and when it gets called, you can write something complexer. However, maybe try this now (not sure if it does anything, just as suggestion): Try this annotation: [HttpPost] before the method.